# Module 'AppleScriptKit' is incompatible with feature 'swift'

Tags: swift, applescript, macos-mojave

I build an iTunes / Spotify controller that sits in the MacOS menu bar a year ago.
It's called [MenuBar](https://ericvulpi.github.io/MusicBar/) for those interested.

I recently upgraded MacOS to Mojave, which of course broke the application I had painstakingly written.

Since there is no match for my app on the mac :), I tried to digg back into the code to see if I could fix things and I get the following error :

> Module 'AppleScriptKit' is incompatible with feature 'swift'

The file that is actually triggering the Swift Compiler Error during the build is the module.modulemap of AppleScriptKit framework (which I import at the beginning of my AppDelegate.swift file). The content of the file is below :

> framework module AppleScriptKit [extern_c] {
>     requires !swift
>     module ASKPluginObject {
>       export *
>       header "ASKPluginObject.h"
>     }
>   }

The last time I successfully compiled was with High Sierra and I'm guessing XCode 9.something.
Now I'm using XCode 10.0.

I've tried to remove and add again the blasted framework.
I've tried to remove it from my app and the part of the app that doesn't use AppleScript works fine (but then it's pretty useless).

Does anyone see a solution ?
Have Apple really removed compatibility of swift with AppleScript ? If yes, what are the recommended alternatives ?

Thanks for your feedback

Comment: AppleScriptKit is part of the long-defunct AppleScript Studio. It's not something you should be using. If you want to call into AppleScript from Swift, use the [AppleScript-ObjC bridge](https://github.com/hhas/Swift-AppleScriptObjC).

Comment: Would be usefull to have some indications when Apple removes compatibility like that... Anyway, thanks for the pointer ! When I try the AppleScriptObjC example you gave, I get the message : Not authorized to send Apple events to iTunes. (error -1743). Do you know how to ask for authorization from the app ?

Comment: The first time an Apple event is sent from one app to another, 10.14 will display a dialog asking the user to grant/forbid access. (Permissions can subsequently be changed in the Privacy tab of System Preferences' security tab.) If you're building against the 10.14 SDK, you must also add an `NSAppleEventsUsageDescription` string to your Info.plist or else it will always fail. [More reading here.](https://www.felix-schwarz.org/blog/2018/08/new-apple-event-apis-in-macos-mojave)

Comment: You rock ! Just for clarity, if anyone else reads this : <NSAppleEventsUsageDescription> corresponds to "Privacy - AppleEvents Sending Usage Description" in the non "raw" version of the Info.plist key list